# why runBlocking is not blocking the invoking thread

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to understand runBlocking in kotlin.

```
 println("before runBlocking ${Thread.currentThread().name}")

    runBlocking { // but this expression blocks the main thread
        delay(2000L) // non blocking
        println("inside runBlocking ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        delay(2000L)
    }

    println("after runBlocking ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
```

Output

```
before runBlocking main
inside runBlocking main
after runBlocking main
```

> ### Kotlin Says
>
> 1. runBlocking - `Runs a new coroutine` and `blocks the current thread` interruptibly until its completion
> 2. The main thread invoking runBlocking blocks until the coroutine inside runBlocking completes.

*point 1 :-* if runBlocking blocked the `main` thread in above example. Then inside runBlocking how i get the `main` thread again.

*point 2 :-* if `Runs a new coroutine` is true in above statement, then why it didn't create new `coroutine` inside `runBlocking`.

Comment: Bro, coroutine is not a thread. 2. Fetch the coroutine name inside by `coroutineContext[CoroutineName]`, 1. runBlocking runs on parent thread(in here main) by blocking it, if no context is provided as parameter.

Comment: Point 1: Apparently runBlocking blocks the main thread from all other use *except* for the new coroutine that it runs. Point 2: It did. What data suggests to you that it didn't?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The signature of `runBlocking` ([doc](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html)) is

```
fun <T> runBlocking(
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T
): T (source)
```

If you see the `context` param, it has a default of an `EmptyCoroutineContext`. Hence when you don't pass a specific context, the default value is an event loop on the current thread. Since the current thread before running the `runBlocking` block was the main thread, whatever you ran inside the block is still on the main thread.

If you pass a coroutine context as below, you would have the block inside `runBlocking` running in a different thread.

```
println("before runBlocking ${Thread.currentThread().name}")

runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) {
    delay(2000L)
    println("inside runBlocking ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    delay(2000L)
}

println("after runBlocking ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
```

Output

```
before runBlocking main
inside runBlocking DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
after runBlocking main
```

Or if you launch `runBlocking` without passing the context, but launch a coroutine inside as below, you would see it running on the different thread.

```
println("before runBlocking ${Thread.currentThread().name}")

runBlocking { 
    println("inside runBlocking ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    delay(2000L) 
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
        println("inside runBlocking coroutineScope ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }
    delay(2000L)
}

println("after runBlocking ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
```

Output

```
before runBlocking main
inside runBlocking main
inside runBlocking coroutineScope DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
after runBlocking main
```

Comment: ok, but why it is giving exception on passing Dispatchers.Main

Comment: @naanu `Dispatchers.Main` is usually used with Main thread operating with UI objects (eg android in the JVM), and you would need to have Android main thread dispatcher in the classpath for it to work. Have a look at the [javaDoc](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/jvm/src/Dispatchers.kt#L35) in the source code