# Kotlin coroutines works with delay but does not work with real computational tasks

Tags: react-native, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a react native app where JS part calls to native kotlin encryption.

I want to use kotlin coroutine and implement as below:

At the same time many encryption tasks call to the native encryption and each task takes 1s.

```
  suspend fun decryptData(<params>): String {
    // computational task
    ....
    return string;
  }

  @ReactMethod
  fun decrypt(<params>) = runBlocking<Unit> {
       val time = measureTimeMillis {
         val op1 = async { decryptData(<params>) }

         promise.resolve("${op1.await()}")
       }
    
       println("Completed in $time ms")
    }
```

[image]

When running without delay all takes:

```
  suspend fun decryptData(<params>): String {
    // computational task
    ....
    return string;
  }

  @ReactMethod
  fun decrypt(<params>) = runBlocking<Unit> {
       val time = measureTimeMillis {
         val op1 = async { decryptData(<params>) }
         val op2 = async { decryptData(<params>) }
         val op3 = async { decryptData(<params>) }
         val op4 = async { decryptData(<params>) }
         val op5 = async { decryptData(<params>) }

         promise.resolve("${op1.await()}, ${op2.await()}, ${op3.await()}, ${op4.await()}, ${op5.await()}")
       }
    
       println("Completed in $time ms")
    }
```

[image]

When running with 3s delay all takes:

```
suspend fun decryptData(<params>): String {
    // computational task
    ....
    delay(3000)
    return string;
}
```

[image]

If the delays are serial then it will take an additional 3*5 = 15s but the delays in couroutine work and are concurrent

But still the real computational tasks are serial!

Comment: Try `runBlocking<Unit>(Dispatchers.Default) {` perhaps? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61384968/5133585

Comment: great! it helps me decrease by 1.5 - 2s. is it Coroutines limit for a 5 tasks of 1s each? I might consider thread for more performance.

Comment: How many cores does your computer have?

Comment: My testing device is Xiaomi Note 8 Pro and it uses Mediatek Helio G90T, Octa-core (2x Cortex-A76 + 6x Cortex-A55) processor.